# Telegram API HTML Links with <pre> tag

Tags: html, telegram

Trying to send text to the bot with 'pre' tags

```
<pre> my table</pre>
```

And it is working fine.
But I need links right there in a table, so I have added

```
<a href>
```

So now I have

```
<pre> my table numer <a href=/"http://google.com/">Google com</a></pre>
```

But this doesnt work. I am just getting text with monospace. If I remove  tag everytihng is fine, but then my table is not a table
How to handle it?

Get preformatted text htmltext

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.

BTW you can inside pre use link references then put the links after closing pre

Ex:

```html
<pre> my table numer Google com [1]</pre> 

[1] <a href="http://google.com/">http://google.com/</a>
```